# WordPress Front Page not working

Tags: wordpress

I'm very confused here. I am very familiar with Wordpress, however, I cannot get the home page of my site to display the HTML and PHP etc that is currently in my home page template.

I have gone to settings - reading and set the home page to a static home page under 'Home', which as you can imagine has the page template for the HTML/PHP I want to display.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any other external factors that affect the home page and the templates being brought through on my other pages are actually working - it's very odd.

I have checked the DOM on the browser multiple times, using Chrome, however none of the divs etc are showing.

Here is the code for the front page so far:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Home Page Template */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?> 


<div class="header_banner">

    <div class="image_content">
        <div class="image">
            <video playsinline="" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" poster="" onplaying="this.controls=false">
                <source src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/videos/video_background.mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video element.
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="main_content center center_absolute">
        <h1>I create and design websites.</h1>
        <h2>I specialise in HTML, CSS, jQuery and Wordpress.</h2>
     </div>

     <div class="center_scroll">
         <div class="scroll">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </div>
     </div>

</div>


<?php get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rename the file to page-home.php since this template will only be used once on your site. Maybe this helps.

Comment: From the PHP documentation http://php.net/basic-syntax.phptags - "it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file." May I suggest you delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the page you selected in the dropdown menu under  **Settings > reading** does not have "*Home Page Template*" template selected under "Page Attributes" Meta Box.

Comment: Hi, I have selected the actual template in the page attributes box for the actual page. This is why it's confusing me haha, unless I've deleted some sort of PHP you need in the header by default to bring through templates, then my ideas on why this isn't working are coming up empty.

Comment: Yeah, that is strange. So what do you get for front page instead?

Comment: Also, what is the name of the template file?

Comment: All I get is the header and footer. Even weirder, when I delete all the PHP and HTML from the home page template file so it's completely empty, the header and footer still show when I reload/view the page.

Comment: The name of the template file is home_page_template.php

Comment: I tried to use your template file name and your template code on my local machine and there is no issue with it, it just works.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is to try to rename it to front-page.php and for the page leave "Page Attributes" to "Default Template"

Comment: Just tried that, absolutely nothing changed. This is very weird.

Comment: And if you select any other page in Settings > Reading, do you get the same result?

Comment: If I change the static front page there as you just mentioned to another page, nothing changes no

Comment: Sorry, but I ran out of ideas. Maybe someone can be more of the help to you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for helping anyway! Appreciate it.

Comment: Hi. I still have your interesting issue in my head :). Have you tried to change template to  "Home Page Template" on a regular page not intended to be a front page, for example with a contact page? I'm wondering if the template will work in this case.